# How do I programmatically perform feature detection in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

I'd like to write a java framework, that supports `JRE7` as a baseline, **but** takes advantage of `JRE8` features, if being run in the context of a `JRE8` (upwards compatible??).

(Or maybe I have this backwards... i.e. `JRE8` is the baseline, but degrades gracefully to support `JRE7`).

Does Java provide a way to do this?

#### My attempt / example:

I thought I could address this in a similar manner to `javascript` feature detection, I could programmatically test for the presence of my `Java8` method, if it exists programmatically invoke it, otherwise fallback to `Java7` libraries.

IMO this is a very arduous approach. It'd be great if this "feature toggling/detection" could be handled by the `Java Runtime Environment` / `Java Compiler`. Is this possible, or am I taking crazy pills?

**Disclaimer:** I haven't addressed compilation, which would rule out the usefulness of this solution (if I compile with `Java7`, I can't add `-parameters` to the compiled classes).

```
public class Index {

    void tellme(String yourname) {
        /* ... */
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method tellme = Index.class.getDeclaredMethod("tellme", String.class);
        Method java8Params = null;
        try {
            java8Params = Method.class.getMethod("getParameters");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException t) { /* ignore */ }
        if (java8Params != null) {
            // java 1.8 !!
            Object param = ((Object[]) java8Params.invoke(tellme))[0];
            System.out.printf("(java8) %s %s(%s %s){/*...*/}",
                    tellme.getReturnType(),
                    tellme.getName(),
                    param.getClass().getMethod("getType").invoke(param),
                    param.getClass().getMethod("getName").invoke(param));
        } else {
            // java 1.7 ...
            System.out.printf("(java7) %s %s(%s %s){/*...*/}",
                    tellme.getReturnType(),
                    tellme.getName(),
                    tellme.getParameterTypes()[0].getName(),
                    "arg0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could take advantage of the Java classloader system and just have two _whole applications_, then bootstrap the correct one from `main` depending on the Java version.

Comment: You could possibly look for inspiration at Spring which appears to be doing something similar - http://spring.io/blog/2015/04/03/how-spring-achieves-compatibility-with-java-6-7-and-8

Comment: So at runtime you're trying to determine what language level (ie java 8, 7, etc) the code was compiled to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it’s correct to resort to Reflection to ensure that there are no code dependencies between your general code and the optional API. Since there are different strategies allowed regarding when to resolve class and member references, non-reflective lazy creation that happens to work on one JVM may fail at another.

But this raises the problem that certain operations are hard to implement when every API usage has to be coded via Reflection, especially as you loose compile-time checking, and the runtime performance may suffer as well.

The general solution is to use the OO technology that Java offers from its very beginning. Create an `interface` or an `abstract class` defining the feature. Implement a Java 8 solution and a Java 7 fallback. During your application initialization or when the feature is needed the first time, you make *one* reflective check whether the feature, your optimal solution relies on, is available and if so, instantiate the optimal implementation, but instantiate the fall-back otherwise. From then on, you use the implementation via the interface like an ordinary object.

In simple cases you may reduce the number of classes to two, the base class defining the feature and providing the fall-back behavior, and the specialized subclass overriding the implementation with its specialized one.

Keep the Java 8 implementation in a separate source folder and compile them using a Java 8 compiler. The other code will be compiled using the Java 7 compiler ensuring that there are no dependencies to the Java 8 implementations.

General Java 7 compatible code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Index {
  static final MethodDescription DESC_ACCESSOR;
  static {
    MethodDescription md;
    try {
      Method.class.getMethod("getParameters");// test JRE feature
      // instantiate specialized solution
      md=(MethodDescription) Class.forName("MethodDescriptionJ8").newInstance();
    } catch(ReflectiveOperationException|LinkageError ex) {
      md=new MethodDescription(); // J7 fall-back
    }
    DESC_ACCESSOR=md;
  }

  void tellme(String yourname) {
      /* ... */
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Method tellme = Index.class.getDeclaredMethod("tellme", String.class);
      String desc=DESC_ACCESSOR.get(tellme);
      System.out.println(desc);
  }
}
class MethodDescription {// base class defining application specific feature
    public String get(Method tellme) {// and providing fall-back implementation
      return String.format("(java7) %s %s(%s %s){/*...*/}",
          tellme.getReturnType(),
          tellme.getName(),
          tellme.getParameterTypes()[0].getName(),
          "arg0");
    }
}
```

compile separately using Java 8:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

public class MethodDescriptionJ8 extends MethodDescription {
    @Override
    public String get(Method tellme) {
      Parameter param = tellme.getParameters()[0];
      return String.format("(java8) %s %s(%s %s){/*...*/}",
                    tellme.getReturnType(),
                    tellme.getName(),
                    param.getType(),
                    param.getName());
    }
}
```

But note that regarding *this specific feature* the result might be disappointing. Parameter *names* are only available if the introspected class was compiled using Java 8 with the `-parameters` flag. Therefore, inspecting the Java 7 compatible classes won’t give you the parameter names, even when using the Java 8 methods at runtime.

Comment: Java 8 allows interfaces to have `default` methods and `static` methods. If one relies on an `interface` as a way to swap Java 7 and Java 8 implementations, they would not be able to use `default` or `static` methods in any of their `interface`. Correct me if I am wrong but just wondering if this would be a limitation of using an `interface` instead of an `abstract` class.

Comment: You can condense all those exceptions you're catching into a single `catch (ReflectiveOperationException ex)`, as of Java 7.  Javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ReflectiveOperationException.html).

Comment: @Chetan Kinger: the base type must be compilable with the lowest common platform, so if you are targeting Java 7 and Java 8, the `interface` must be Java 7 compatible, if you use an `interface` as base type. The consideration whether to use an `abstract class` or an `interface` are the same as they were before Java 8 was introduced. But one additional advantage of an `interface` solution is that if it encapsulates only a single operation expressed as one method that matches a JRE method in Java 8, you may implement the Java 8 version using the `LambdaMetaFactory`…